# How to not display NaN in my Jupyterlab table and bar graph after imported

Tags: python, jupyter

I imported a CSV file into Jupyterlab, but the empty spaces in the excel file give me NaN after importing and displaying them in Jupyterlab. Is there any ways that the NaN can be replaced? I am trying to plot a bar graph and the graph is full of NaN.

I have already tried using df.fillna(""), but the NaNs are still there in the table and the graph.

Comment: does [df.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) help?

Comment: no, it drops the entire contents of the table, leaving only the header of the table